# Cpu and ps2 keyboard communication

Tags: cpu, port, keyboard, ps2

Ok, lets's try again, it's surprising that it is hard to find a clear and sharp enough way to ask such a question.

How is PS2 keyboard data usually decoded to ASCII in hardware level, and then how is it transformed to assembly? Is there always some kind of software interpreter for that?

Comment: far too broad, unspecified, unstructured. There's 5 question marks in your single question, and all of them belong to a question of type "what next?". *ask a **single** and **precise** question*, please.

Comment: I can honestly say I have no idea what your question is. You just seem to be rambling on about keyboard scan codes or something. Have you read what you're written? What is "programmaplememory"?

Comment: Well, yes. You have to do all those things. It's your project. We cannot do it for you. Ask one specific question at which you actually need help. If it's all of them, that would be a long way to go and I suggest you to choose a simpler project.

Comment: Sorry my articulation and mistakes. I cannot make fixes if I don't have allowed. But If someone have not answers to question, critics, or warnings because brake of posting policy, please don't suggest simpler project, it's offtopic.

Comment: I think the OP has way too little knowledge. To the OP: the keyboard uses a specialized serial interface for communication. It isn't decoded into ASCII in hardware. That is done in software. It provides codes for each key press and codes for each key release and treats SHIFT the same as F6, in that regard. Software does all of the handling of shift, ctrl, etc.

Comment: Yes agree I'm have things to learn and  I definetly not have some kind of engineer skills,  but i know, keyboard clock, serial data communication, etc. Anyone won't give me already ready schematics for such a system which I will build, but that's why I'm here because I try now asking from forums some knowledge grains, instead of only reading ,tutorial guides, free e-books example.I know something about interpreters and compilers. The thing which I now try to find good example is how PS2 keyboard arrives to cpu 1/0 and how is handled by cpu and in some architecture way in execution cycle.

Comment: Google helps. Try this: http://retired.beyondlogic.org/keyboard/keybrd.htm to start out.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is not done in the hardware. There is a piece of software in the operating system called the "keyboard driver" that is responsible for converting the raw key codes into ASCII (and other) data. This is what gives it the flexibility to have alternate key maps and handle other special functions.

If you want to do the same thing in an embedded processor, you'll have to duplicate the function of the keyboard driver in your own firmware.